# Getting parameters through tokens in a char array

Tags: c, parsing, token

I have a text file with a output similar to this style:

> some text  10 trials other text here 12 trials and a bit more txt 20 trials
>
> some text here  7 trials text 16 trials and more txt 20 trials
>
> etc

What I'm trying to do is getting the values before **trials** I have a code that work theoretically but breaks because the  text is manipulated  isn't the same as when you run `strcmp()`

```
char *fileToString(char *fileName){
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "rb");
    long lSize;

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    char *buffer = malloc(lSize);
    fread(buffer, 1, lSize, file);
    fclose(file);
    return buffer;
}
```

The main looks something like this.

```
    path[20] = "path/to/file.txt";
    char *a = fileToString(path);
    char trial[6] = "trials";
    char *token, *tmp;
    token = strtok(a, " \n");
    tmp = token;
    while(token != NULL){
        if(strcmp(token, trial)==0){
            printf("%s trials\n", tmp);
        }
        printf("tmp: %s | token %s | strcmp %d\n", tmp, token, strcmp(token,trial));
        tmp = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        
    }
```

The result should be

```
10 trials
12 trials
20 trials
7 trials
16 trials
20 trials
```

etc but the `strcmp(token, trial)` sometimes gives me non-zero even when the `token` and `trial` should be matching. When I printed the `strcmp()` values this is what I got in the result

```
tmp: 12 | token trials | strcmp -81
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pay attention at

```
 char trial[6] = "trials";
```

Here `trial[6]` should be `trial[7]` to store not only letters, but also `'\0'` (end of line)

Comment: Alternatively `char *trial = "trials"` which doesn't specify a length but simply assigns a pointer.

Comment: I also wouldn't call `'\0'` the "end of line". A newline or end of line is `'\n'`. I'd call `'\0'` the termination byte or character.

Comment: Or `char trial[] = "trials";` which allocates automatically the correct number of chars.